# vscode - How to delete (send to recycle bin) project using vscode when having open multuple projects

Tags: visual-studio-code

Having opened multiple projects with vscode,
[image]

is there any way or plugin so I can delete (send to recycle bin) one of the projects?

*Note: Not possible to be removed with context (right click)*
[image]

Comment: These are just folders in your workspace directory.
It should be possible to simply left click - delete the folders

Comment: I am afraid, this is not possible. I just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

What about this Option, it should remove the Folder from yor Workspace as intended:

[image]

What happens if you try?

Comment: Hey, sry for the late answer. No, this is only removing from the workspace. I tried all those things before asking the question.